# Rattle Mac Sierra10.13.6 cannot run Errors nor OOB ROC from conditional random forests

Tags: r, random, rattle

I would apprecaite some help!

I am running rattle on a Mac with MacOS high Sierra 10.13.6. It took me really long to make all work. Now it is all functional except for the functions Errors and OOB ROC from conditional random forests.

I get persistent messages like:

> Error: $ operator not defined for this S4 class

Some others are related to masked fucntions, like:

> The following object is masked from ‘package:base’:
>   For this I tried to dettach all the packages masking rattle, but it did not work.

Another error I get and I have not been able to understand is:

> (R:5515): Gtk-WARNING **: 15:31:44.163: Attempting to set the permissions of `/Users/Criz/.local/share/recently-used.xbel', but failed: No such file or directory
>   For this one I tried to reset the language settings, but it did not work either.

I am quite lost on how to start to find the problems in the configuration or the reasons why the commands do not work. Any help is appreciated.

THANKS

Comment: You should show the code you are running when you get these errors.

Comment: For instance, when running:
library(verification)
aucc <- verification::roc.area(as.integer(as.factor(na.omit(crs$dataset[,])[, crs$target]))-1,
                 crs$rf$votes[,2])$A
verification::roc.plot(as.integer(as.factor(na.omit(crs$dataset[,])[, crs$target]))-1,
         crs$rf$votes[,2], main="")
legend("bottomright", bty="n",
       sprintf("Area Under the Curve (AUC) = %1.3f", aucc))
title(main="OOB ROC Curve Random Forest pers_AV.csv")

 I get:
> Error in crs$rf$votes : $ operator not defined for this S4 class

Comment: Show the code in the question with an [edit]. Comments can be deleted.